# subquery in django

Tags: django, subquery

I have 2 models:

```
class Professors(models.Model):
    professors_name = models.CharField('professor', max_length=32, unique=True)
class Discipline(models.Model):
    auditorium = models.IntegerField('auditorium')
    professors_name = models.ForeignKey(Professors)
```

In views:

```
disciplines = Discipline.objects.all()
```

So, I have number of auditorium and professors_name_id. But I need full profrssors name, not id. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models:

```
# models usually named in the singular
class Professor(models.Model):
    professors_name = models.CharField('professor', max_length=32, unique=True) 
class Discipline(models.Model):
    auditorium = models.IntegerField('auditorium')
    # your pointer is to a professor, not to the name
    professor = models.ForeignKey(Professor)
```

In view:

```
# select_related('professor') to avoid a second query when accessing professor
disciplines = Discipline.objects.select_related('professor')
```

Template:

```
{% for disc in disciplines %}
{{ disc.auditorium }}: {{ disc.professor.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

For values:

```
Discipline.objects.values('auditorium', 'professor__name')
```

Answer (score 1):

Django ORM will always returns the objects not the ids. You should have a design like this.

```
class Professor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('professor', max_length=32, unique=True)
class Discipline(models.Model):
    auditorium = models.IntegerField('auditorium')
    professor = models.ForeignKey(Professors)
```

and use `discipline.professor.name` to retrieve the name alone.

Comment: I use disciplines = Discipline.objects.values('auditorium', 'discipline.professor.name') and it doesnt work

Comment: That it's not what @Siva meant. If you use disciplines = Discipline.objects.all() then each instance inside that queryset has a professor name through discipline.professor.name